# How does the SignIn screen get called in Cannonball for iOS?

Tags: swift, twitter-digits

I'm new to Digits for iOS.  I got the authentication part working, and now I'm trying to integrate the sign-in with the rest of my app.

One thing that really puzzles me is that in Cannonball, the Initial View Controller is the main screen.  However, when running Cannonball, the first screen I see is the Sign In screen.

I don't see any segue from the Navigation Controller to the Sign In.  Also, I've looked at the code in the Theme Chooser View Controller, and don't see any reference to the Sign In's View Controller.

So, how does the Sign In screen actually get executed?  Where is that logic happening?  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the AppDelegate.swift file does the logic.  The code below were copy/pasted from Cannonball's.  I went ahead and added comments (some came with Cannonball).

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Developers: Welcome! Get started with Fabric.app.
    let welcome = "Welcome to Cannonball! Please onboard with the Fabric Mac app. Check the instructions in the README file."
    assert(NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("Fabric") != nil, welcome)

    // Register Crashlytics, Twitter, Digits and MoPub with Fabric.
    //Fabric.with([Crashlytics(), Twitter(), Digits(), MoPub()])
    Fabric.with([Digits()])

    // Check for an existing Twitter or Digits session before presenting the sign in screen.
    // Detect if the Digits session is nil
    // if true, set the root view controller to the Sign In's view controller
    if Twitter.sharedInstance().session() == nil && Digits.sharedInstance().session() == nil {
        //Main corresponds to Main.storyboard
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        //Sign In's View Controller
        let signInViewController: AnyObject! = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignInViewController")
        //Set the UIWindow's ViewController to the SignIn's ViewController
        window?.rootViewController = signInViewController as? UIViewController
    }
    return true
}
```